# rails bootstrap popover stops working when form has validation errors

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm on Rails 6 using Bootstrap 5. I have a form that uses bootstrap popovers, when the form has errors the Rails validations will prevent it from being submitted and the popovers no longer work when there are validation errors. I tried testing with jQuery and I get the same results.

I know it's due to the fact that I'm calling `$(function(){ .... }` and `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... }` which I need in order to get the popovers to initialize and work when the form loads.  **But I'm not sure how to display the popover again if there are errors in the form.**

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

// bootstrap popover's
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })
});
```

jQuery test that also only works until the form is submitted with errors.

```
$(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a binding issue to me, try binding the event with `body`

```
$("body").on("hover", "p", function(){
  // remaining code
});
```